# ObjectDataSource sets MaximumRowsParameterName= -1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a GridView and an ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="myType" SelectMethod="FindByName"
    MaximumRowsParameterName="NumRows" StartRowIndexParameterName="RowStart" EnablePaging="true">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="namex" Type="String" Direction="Input" DefaultValue="" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RowStart" Type="Int32" Direction="Input" DefaultValue="0" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="NumRows" Type="Int32" Direction="Input" DefaultValue="15"/>
   </SelectParameters>
```

Everyting seems to work fine.
But when i change page on GridView and the ObjectDataSource calls the method it sends the parametter NumRows=-1(StartRowIndexParameterName="NumRows").
If i call ObjectDataSource.Select() it sends NumRows=0

even if i set a value to the parameter NumRows

```
Protected Sub ObjectDataSource_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles ObjectDataSource.Selecting
        e.InputParameters("NumRows") = 15
End Sub
```

ObjectDataSource still sends -1 or 0.
To parameter RowStart it sends the right value(click page 1 sends 0, click on page 2 sends 15...)

Comment: You must set the SelectCountMethod to your ObjectDataSource, Did my answer solve the problem?

Comment: Well I am not working on it anymore (i dont have the source code), but i do want to try it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectCountMethod` property of `ObjectDataSource` control is set to the name of a method that returns the total number of records in the query.

You must implement your data source as the following :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
    TypeName="myType"
    SelectMethod="FindByName"
    SelectCountMethod="GetMyTypeCount"

    MaximumRowsParameterName="NumRows"
    StartRowIndexParameterName="RowStart"

    EnablePaging="true">

    <%--TODO : ...--%>

</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

or you can follow examples of [this URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.maximumrowsparametername.aspx).